# getting values from combobox tied to dataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combobox that is tied to a datatable. I would like to be able to get the values for both the DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath items in the selected item. Here's what I have:

```
private void CboCustomerList_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

    string connectionString = Settings.Default.ProdConnectionString;
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlCmd.CommandText = "sp_GetItemIds";
    SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@customer", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = CboCustomerList.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim();
    SqlCmd.Connection = connection;
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter();
    sqlDa.SelectCommand = SqlCmd;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();


    try
    {
        sqlDa.Fill(ds, "ITEMS");
        DataRow nRow = ds.Tables["ITEMS"].NewRow();
        nRow["EXTITEM"] = string.Empty;
        nRow["ITEMID"] = "0";
        ds.Tables["ITEMS"].Rows.InsertAt(nRow, 0);

        //Binding the data to the combobox.
        CboItemId.DataContext = ds.Tables["ITEMS"].DefaultView;
        connection.Close();

        CboItemId.DisplayMemberPath =
            ds.Tables["ITEMS"].Columns["EXTITEM"].ToString();

        CboItemId.SelectedValuePath =
            ds.Tables["ITEMS"].Columns["ITEMID"].ToString();


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
        SqlCmd.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to get the selected value and selected Item values based on selection in Combo box . if so, you can get it on selection changed event  `private void CboItemId_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        string item = CboItemId.SelectedItem.ToString(); string val = CboItemId.SelectedValue.ToString(); }`

Answer (score 0):

you can get it on selection changed event

```
  private void CboItemId_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) 
  { 
      string item = CboItemId.SelectedItem.ToString();
      string val = CboItemId.SelectedValue.ToString();
  }
```

Comment: this returns "System.Data.DataRowView"

Comment: @rigamonk: does your combo box displays the binded data

Answer (score -1):

You've probably got it by now (asked 3 years ago) but you've got to set the display member and value member before binding the data to the combobox.